# Kalman Filter Under Non-Gaussian Noise

Tags: noise, kalman-filters, gaussian, adaptive-filters

I know that Kalman filter is optimal filter under some assumption like process and measurement noise are Gaussian. But if the process and measurement noise is non-Gaussian, the estimation of the Kalman filter will start to be inaccurate, especially with noisy measurements. Can you suggest adaptive Kalman filter algorithm for non-Gaussian noise condition?

Comment: Anything other than Gaussian... has a wide variation. Can you add some detail regarding what specific non-Gaussian characteristics your noise regime has?

Comment: First, "adaptive filter" narrows the list of possibilities down too far -- you want to ask for non-linear approaches in general.  Second, either do as @PeterK. asks and _edit your question_ to describe your specific problem, or to make it clear that you're looking for a survey answer that talks about _all_ the possible approaches.  Dealing with nonlinear systems or non-Gaussian noise, or cost functions that aren't quadratic isn't a nice deductive process like the Kalman filter -- you end up applying a bag of tricks, and different situations require different tricks.

Comment: Example of non-gaussian noise is shot noise or time varying noise.